# How to split the pandas column into two

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['asdf', 'xy', 'q'], 'col2': [(2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]})
```

I have dataframe above. I wish to split the column col2 such as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['asdf', 'xy', 'q'], 'col2': [2, 2, 3], 'col3': [1, 2, 3]})
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) and 2D assignment:

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df['col2'].tolist()
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  asdf     2     1
1    xy     2     2
2     q     3     3
```

Or, if you want to remove 'col2' and assign to another name, using [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df[['col3', 'col4']] = df.pop('col2').tolist()
```

output:

```
   col1  col3  col4
0  asdf     2     1
1    xy     2     2
2     q     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possible solution:

```
df['col2'], df['col3'] = zip(*df.col2)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  asdf     2     1
1    xy     2     2
2     q     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.Series`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) constructor :

```
df[['col2','col3']] = df['col2'].apply(pd.Series)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0  asdf     2     1
1    xy     2     2
2     q     3     3
```

Comment: Quick note on efficiency, this requires to loop over all columns which is not really efficient compared to the use of the underlying list ;)

Comment: I was about to post the underlying list approach but you were too fast ;)